# Android Horizontal progress bar

Tags: android, progress-bar

The horizontal progress bar gives you a fraction and a percentage of how much progress it has.
I would like to remove the fraction, and keep the percentage. I'll appreciate your answers.
Note that my minimum API level is 7.

Perhaps I was not clear enough with question, here is the code that shows the progress bar. Pretty straightforward.

```
myProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
                myProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                myProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                myProgressDialog.setProgress(0);
                myProgressDialog.setMax(max);
                myProgressDialog.show();
```

the `setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);` shows a progress bar. While your progress is being incremented you get progress percentage on the widget as well a progress fraction for example if `max` was 100.

```
 _____________________
|=============________|
60%       60/100
```

this is the widget style provided by android. I want to remove that fraction

Comment: As CommonsWare mentioned in his answer below, a horizontal ProgressBar doesn't give you a fraction. Is it possible that you are using someone else's code with an incomplete understanding of how it works? If that is the case, it would certainly be to your advantage to spend a little more time trying to understand the code. If you have specific questions about what a given block of code does, then post those questions here with the relevant code block.

Comment: I didn't assume anything - notice that I formulated my comment as a question. That question was informed by the fact that you were talking about a ProgressBar displaying a fraction (which it does not). Had you instead referred to ProgressDialog or posted your code (which I see you did in an edit), then that question would have been unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The horizontal `ProgressBar` widget is a bar. It does not "give you a fraction".

Comment: Call `setProgressNumberFormat(null)` on `myProgressDialog`.

Comment: Oh, sorry -- didn't notice that the method was new. I doubt it can be controlled by a style. Just write your own dialog.